# AWS ATHENA Transpose from column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a csv file uploaded to an S3 bucket which I pick up with AWS Glue then query using Athena. The CSV table is in the format below:

| ID | Starting Time | Ending Time | Failure Sector | Recycling Rounds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5am/8am/1pm | 6am/10am/3pm | /(5)/ | 0/0/ |
| 2 | 4am/6am/3pm/7pm | 7am/8am/5pm/11pm | ///(1) | 1//1/ |

I want to convert that format into this:

| ID | Starting Time | Ending Time | Failure Sector | Recycling Rounds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5am | 6am | blank | 0 |
| 1 | 8am | 10am | (5) | 0 |
| 1 | 1pm | 3pm | blank | blank |
| 2 | 4am | 7am | blank | 1 |
| 2 | 6am | 8am | blank | blank |
| 2 | 3pm | 5pm | blank | 1 |
| 2 | 7pm | 11pm | (1) | blank |

How do I accomplish that using SQL in Athena?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to transform varchar into array of varchars and then flatten with [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) which supports multiple arrays:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (ID, Starting_Time, Ending_Time, Failure_Sector, Recycling_Rounds) AS
         (VALUES (1, '5am/8am/1pm', '6am/10am/3pm', '/(5)/', '0/0/'),
                 (2, '4am/6am/3pm/7pm', '7am/8am/5pm/11pm', '///(1)', '1//1/'))

-- query
select st, et, fs, rr
from dataset,
unnest (split(Starting_Time,'/'), split(Ending_Time,'/'), split(Failure_Sector,'/'), split(Recycling_Rounds,'/')) 
    as t(st, et, fs, rr);
```

Output:

| st | et | fs | rr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5am | 6am |  | 0 |
| 8am | 10am | (5) | 0 |
| 1pm | 3pm |  |  |
| 4am | 7am |  | 1 |
| 6am | 8am |  |  |
| 3pm | 5pm |  | 1 |
| 7pm | 11pm | (1) |  |

Comment: Thanks! It works in the Athena AWS! But when I want to put it into Glue job ETL script, it failed as error: 'UnresolvedTableValuedFunction unnest, ['split('Starting_Time, /),  'split('Ending Time , /)]. Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: And this error---- ParseException: "\nextraneous input ';' expecting <EOF>.

Comment: @Yoga sorry, TBH have not setup the data transforms in Glue but I believe it should be done some other way and not by sql queries.